# "Torpedo remote detonator" vs "remote torpedo detonator"?

Tags: adjectives

This question is for game I am working on. I read about adjective order and I tried google something similar but still not sure which version is correct or is there any difference at all. Thanks!

Comment: Try to feel for which premodifier is more strongly associated with the head noun 'detonator'. Would you say that it's more significant to think of a torpedo detonator, or a remote detonator? I'd go with 'remote torpedo detonator'. Though neither is 'ungrammatical'.

Comment: For me it's clearly "remote torpedo detonator". Hands down. The other option isn't even an option. I cannot even force it to be.

Comment: @RegDwigнt it would be if there was such a thing as a 'torpedo remote'.

Comment: I think about second option too but I feel a bit confused that "tv remote control" is way more popular than "remote tv control" (I googled both). Isn't this similar issue or I don't understand something?

Comment: @RegDwigнt It depends on whether you think of the detonator as being a device for triggering a torpedo which is at a distance from the device (a remote torpedo detonator) or a device which triggers a torpedo when it is at a distance from the torpedo (a torpedo remote detonator). Physically these describe the same situation but they differ in perspective. As the OP says in a comment the second option is similar to "tv remote control" where the emphasis is on the fact that the control is at a distance from the equipment being controlled rather than the other way round. I prefer the second form.

Comment: Thanks for all answers! It was really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual it depends on what you wish to modify. The pointy tip of the torpedo has [most of us assume] a detonator. It is the remoteness that is the most important part of your invention. You are modifying the location of the detonator to your local control. That is a remote detonator. For this reason the "Remote" must be out in front describing the torpedo detonator, or just the detonator. So go with remote torpedo detonator or just remote detonator.

You are worried it might sound like you are detonating your remote torpedo. Don't be. I should hope it would be remote however it gets detonated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will use second version.